# Finding background images in Foundation Emails' gulp process?

Tags: email, gulp, zurb-foundation

ZURB's Foundation for Emails has a gulp process for looking at the HTML it produces, finding all the images referenced in it, and adding them all to a .zip file. However, it finds those images by searching for img selectors, and so misses anything referenced as a background image in a style tag, or  tag (the fallback for Outlook).

```
style="background-image:url('image.jpg');"
<v:fill src="image.jpg" />
```

The original gulp task looks like;

```
  var moveImages = gulp.src(sourcePath)
  .pipe($.htmlSrc({ selector: 'img'}))
  .pipe($.rename(function (path) {
    path.dirname = fileName + '/' + path.dirname;
    return path;
  }));
```

(sourcePath is the reference to the HTML file)

I've modified this to just find ALL the images it can in a directory (and flatten the zip - ignore the difference in path.dirname);

```
  var moveImages = gulp.src(dist+'/assets/img/*')
  .pipe($.rename(function (path) {
    path.dirname = '';
    return path;
  }));
```

This works, however, as I create more and more emails, the images stored in assets/img will grow more numerous, and each email will generate a .zip that's bigger and bigger, unnecessarily.

**How can I add to the default moveImages task to find all the images in the HTML, without just resorting to pulling in the whole directory of them?**

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't figure out how to explicitly look for background images, I did solve this in a slightly hacky way;

Where I have a background image, I added after it an inline image that was hidden, and tagged for removal later on;

```
      <!-- Inline background image so build process picks it up. -->
  <div style="display: none; max-height: 0px; font-size: 0px; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all" class="destroyme">
    <img src="assets/img/header-background.png">
  </div>
```

And then in the gulp process when moving HTML, I remove that .destroyme div;

```
var moveHTML = gulp.src(sourcePath)
  .pipe($.replace('assets/img/', '' ))
  .pipe($.htmlRemove('.destroyme'))
  .pipe($.rename(function (path) {
    path.dirname = '';
    return path;
  }));
```

Using: https://github.com/gevgeny/gulp-html-remove

npm install --save-dev gulp-html-remove

That way, when the html is built in /dist for local preview purposes, the duplicate image isn't shown, and when it's zipped, the "background" image is pulled in to the images folder, and the duplicate removed from the HTML source.

It's not exactly what I wanted, and requires an extra step when you're building emails, but it does work (for me at least)...